# Структуры. Выделение памяти в структуре для строк по указателям

Tags: c++, структуры

Нашел в интернете такой пример использования структуры

```
struct building     //Создаем структуру!
{                  
    char *owner;       //здесь будет храниться имя владельца
    char *city;        //название города
    int amountRooms;   //количество комнат
    float price;       //цена
};                 

int main()
{
    building apartment1;   //это объект структуры с типом данных, именем структуры, building

    apartment1.owner = "Денис"; //заполняем данные о владельце и т.д.
    apartment1.city = "Симферополь";      
    apartment1.amountRooms = 5;
    apartment1.price = 150000;
```

Для *owner и *city - что-то не вижу выделения памяти, значит ли это, что данные запишутся хз куда, и не удалятся по завершении программы?

Comment: а какой язык то? Вы в `char *` пихаете `const char *` и компилятор молчит? Короткий ответ - всё в целом нормально с памятью.

Comment: @pavel, язык C++, по сути я создаю объект структуры, и в одно из полей, обозначенное как char * пихаю строку. Что меня и смущает, ведь char * - просто указатель, он не предоставляет места для хранения.

Comment: конечно это ответом стоило писать, но явно Harry лучше опишет) Если по-простому. Компилятор кстати меняйте, предупредить он должен. Все константы хранятся в спец памяти (константной, статической и так далее) их туда компилятор загоняет. На неё можно получить указатель `const char *` вы его кастуете (неявно) в `char *` и сохраняете. Попробуйте заменить символ в строке (любой) и 99% что программа упадёт (почему не 100, так UB оно такое).

Comment: @pavel Гм, нанять вас литературным агентом, что ли? :) Если программа скомпилирована VC++, то 99% что она не упадет, но просто ничего не изменится (уж лучше б она падала)...

Comment: @Harry а можно подробнее? Ничего это совсем ничего или все эти константы будут испорчены? Я так `%d` любил оверрайдить на старых компиляторах.

Comment: @Harry В защиту VC++ скажу, что в VS2017 такой код с флагами по-умолчанию (`/permissive-`) вызовет ошибку компиляции. Для более старых версий есть опция `/Zc:strictStrings`.

Comment: @VTT Ну, тогда ура :) Ага, если совсем без ключиков - падает. Но стоит дать /O2 - как все, просто молча игнорирует. VC++2017 А поскольку MSDN про этот ключ пишет *" (этот параметр используется по умолчанию для окончательных построений)"*, то все равно грустно... И на `char*=".."` тоже даже при `/W4` не реагирует.

Comment: @Harry [`/permissive-` используется по-умолчанию для новых проектов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance), причем во всех конфигурациях. Ну а в старых проектах его придется выставлять вручную.

Comment: Ага, т.е. тут идет неявное определение данных как констант, с получением адреса константы в указатель, и все эти данные потом стандартно удалятся. Всем спасибо)

Comment: @VTT D проекте - может быть, но не в командной строке...

Comment: Код не является корректным ни с точки зрения C (`building` - нет такого типа), ни с точки зрения С++ (нельзя указывать на строковый литерал при помощи `char *`). На каком языке это написано? И почему поставлены тэги [С] и [C++], да еще и одновременно?

Comment: @AnT Тег C я поставил по невнимательности (уже убрал). Написано на языке C++, вернее так уверяет вот эта статья [ссылка](http://cppstudio.com/post/7008/). И я сам был в замешательстве, почему `char *` указывает на строку и нет ли здесь утечки памяти. Как я понял, нет.

Comment: @GenrixStraus Из-за отсутствия `const` в `char *` этот код не является корректным с точки зрения современного С++. В оригинальном С++98 это действительно было допустимо.

Comment: @AnT получается неопределенное поведение, и результат будет зависеть от компилятора?

Comment: @GenrixStraus Формально да. А фактически "зависимость от компилятора" выльется в его согласие или несогласие это компилировать. Если согласится - то все должно работать нормально. (Разумеется, если вы не будете пытаться модифицировать эти литералы через эти указатели.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные останутся *на своем месте*, т.е. никуда не переместятся и не перезапишутся. В ваших полях `owner` и `city` хранятся указатели на них (адреса первых символов).

Так что вы не можете их удалять (не вздумайте написать `delete[]city`, например) - они не были выделены динамически, и не имеете права их перезаписывать (типа `city[0]='A'`) - это строковые литералы.

Answer (score 2):

Строковый литерал в С и С++ является немодифицируемым объектом типа "массив" со *статическим* классом памяти. То есть когда вы в своем коде пишете `"Симферополь"` вы фактически создаете безымянный символьный массив, который фактически является статической переменной. Она существует с самого начала жизни программы и до самого ее конца. Вся необходимая память уже выделена и освобождать ее - не ваша задача.

Answer (score 0):

по хорошему имя владельца и название города в структуре должны быть константными

```
    struct building     //Создаем структуру!
{                  
    const char *owner;       //здесь будет храниться имя владельца
    const char *city;        //название города
    int amountRooms;   //количество комнат
    float price;       //цена
};
```

тогда с main() все нормально, так как инициализация есть выделение памяти

Comment: с каких пор  структуры с константными данными невозможно копировать  господин эксперт?

Comment: не тот const, согласен. Но ответа ж это не добавит.

Comment: вы не правы, ответ не только означает прямой ответ на прямой вопрос, но и ответ с поправкой тоже ответ, а вот когда вы минусуюте не понимая или не имея желания соображать, вот это уже некрасиво

Comment: что инициализация есть выделение памяти, это не ответ на вопрос того человека, который не видел выделение памяти?...

Comment: выделение памяти и инициализация это два разных действия, они могут существовать независимо друг от друга.

Comment: мой дорогой, я занимаюсь программированием меньше времени, чем вы находитесь в этом сайте, но вы всегда отвечаете на тривиальные вопросы, поэтому хотя и ваш рейтинг выше, но с такими знаниями вам не мне учить... Вы путаете понятия следует с равносильностью.  Я не написал, что выделение памяти есть инициализация, а написал ясно, что инициализация есть выделение памяти. Это совершенно разные вещи, и если вы не правильно понимаете  русский язык или плохо знаете С++,  тогда просто изучайте сами, а не пытайтесь учить меня